# EJB not Reconnecting after new deployment

Tags: java, spring, ejb, weblogic, reconnect

We have 2 Java applications talking to each other via EJB's on 2 different servers.

The EJB is defined in Spring with the ejb name setup as a foreign JNDI in web logic.

```
<bean id="codingRemote" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/myEjb" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.my.ej.binterface" />
    <property name="refreshHomeOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I have the refreshHomeOnConnectFailure set to true and I can restart the remote server and it re connects but the thing is if I redeploy to the remote server (our deploy process removes the web logic domain completely, recreates it and deploys the new artifacts) it seems to try to connect but there are security problems.

On the remote machine I get the following exception after the "redeploy" process and a call is made from the client - hence the client is trying to make the call but the remote machine/JVM is not accepting the call:

```
<Aug 28, 2014 11:20:23 AM CAT> <Warning> <RMI> <WL-080003> <A RuntimeException was generated by the RMI server: weblogic.jndi.internal.AdminRoleBasedDispatchServerRef@9, implementation: 'weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode@ac24b13', oid: '9', implementationClassName: 'weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode'
 java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators].
java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.seal(SecurityServiceManager.java:833)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getSealedSubjectFromWire(SecurityServiceManager.java:522)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.getSubject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:355)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.acceptRequest(BasicServerRef.java:1022)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:350)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Environment Java7 / Weblogic12 / Spring2.5

Any idea how to get passed this to allow the login or user credential login to re-take-place again?

### ----------

I found 2 possible solutions but I am not entirely sure which one is the best to use and if there are any problems in doing so.

**Solution1:** - Specify a JNDI Template but in doing that it defeats the purpose of defining it inside weblogic and now is part of the application it self.

```
<bean id="codingRemote" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/myEjb" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.my.ej.binterface" />
    <property name="refreshHomeOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref local="myProcessJndiTemplate" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myProcessJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${specify.the.context}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${specify.the.url}</prop>
             <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Solution2:** - I found at this [site](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/ejb/11356-weblogic-simpleremotestatelesssessionproxyfactorybean-and-initialcontext) that if we Override the SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean we can instantiate the security again.

```
public class WebLogicSimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean extends SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean {

    @Override protected Object create() throws NamingException, InvocationTargetException {

        try {

            return getJndiTemplate().execute(new JndiCallback() {
                public Object doInContext(final Context context) throws NamingException {
                    try {
                        return WebLogicSimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.super.create();
                    } catch (final InvocationTargetException ite) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ite);
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (final RuntimeException re) {

            throw (InvocationTargetException) re.getCause();

        }

    }

    protected void removeSessionBeanInstance(final EJBObject ejbObject) {

        try {

            getJndiTemplate().execute(new JndiCallback() {
                public Object doInContext(final Context context) throws NamingException {
                    WebLogicSimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.super.removeSessionBeanInstance(ejbObject);
                    return null;
                }
            });

        } catch (final NamingException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

    }

    protected Object doInvoke(final MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

        try {

            return getJndiTemplate().execute(new JndiCallback() {
                public Object doInContext(final Context context) throws NamingException {
                    try {
                        return WebLogicSimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.super.doInvoke(methodInvocation);
                    } catch (final Throwable t) {
                        if (t instanceof NamingException) {
                            throw (NamingException) t;
                        } else {
                            throw new RuntimeException(t);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (final RuntimeException re) {

            throw re.getCause();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is that error from the client or remote server log? Also have you set `Home>DomainName>Security`, and checked `Cross Domain Security Enabled` on both domains? This syncs the weblogic user password on both domains so they can talk without the error you're seeing above

Comment: The error is on the server. Even after deleted the domain, recreated it and apply the Cross Domain setting while the client is running.

I found 2 possible solutions but I am not entirely sure which one is the best to use and if there are any problems in doing so.